# Replicating environment from renderdoc to debug

Tags: c++, debugging, vulkan, renderdoc

I have a strange issue, a vulkan application I am writing seemingly runs fine when run from the terminal. But if run from renderdoc an assertion inside the official .hpp header triggers.

Since this only happens if the program is launched with renderdoc I am having a hard time trying to debug it.

Is there a way to get the exact environment configuration renderdoc is using to run the program so that I can replicate the bug?

It is quite bizarre it only happens if the new dynamic rendering extension is active too. If it is not requested renderdoc doesn;t seem to trigger the assertion. But I am on the latest version (1.18).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs into something like this in teh future. The problem was that an old instance of renderdoc was installed in my system, this in turn created conflicts when loading the program onto renderdoc as vulkan wasn't properly configured.

Uninstalling the old version fixed it.